# Powershell CSV query

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I was wondering how do get the output from Win32_LogicalDisk to a csv?

So far I have the following:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName comp1,comp2,comp3|Add-Content 'C:\Book1.csv'
```

When I run it, a lot of information and columns are missing in the CSV. It's a growing CSV file and export-csv seems to over write the csv.

I really appreciate your help,

Ryan

Comment: [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv): `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName comp1,comp2,comp3|Export-Csv 'C:\Book1.csv'

Comment: Thanks but we need to keep an growing CSV for inventory, export CSV will overwrite the existing information.

Comment: `Export-Csv` also has a `-Append` switch..

Comment: Wonderful thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use export-csv

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName comp1,comp2,comp3| export-csv 'C:\Book1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

if you want keep info you can add -append to export-csv command